# The right way to get http referrer from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Command $(document).referrer is the correct way to get referrer with Jquery?

Comment: google: http+referrer+javascript?

Comment: urm I did - that's how I got here :-) plus I never remember how to incorrectly spell `refer*er` correctly

Answer (score 67, accepted):

How about just:

```
document.referrer
```

Comment: That's great if it works, but `document.referrer` is not set in my version, so what's the answer in that case?

Comment: @user9645, what do you mean "your version"?  All modern browsers (and then some) should support `document.referrer`.  That doesn't mean the value is always set, though.  It depends on user settings, extensions, etc.

Comment: here's a couple useful article if you're finding `document.referrer` is null. (most important thing is to make sure your site is https) http://smerity.com/articles/2013/where_did_all_the_http_referrers_go.html
https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/protecting-privacy-with-referrers/392382738919