# How do I get the URL of a previous page which is not part of my project?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, url

What I have to do is get the URL of the previous page no matter what, I mean, if it comes from Google for instance, I have to get Google's URL and so forth... Can anybody help me?

I've tried `Response.Redirect` and also `Request`, `ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]`, however both of them returns null. I've tried JS as well using `document.Referrer`, but nothing's working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the URL Referrer as explained in this SO post: [Getting the HTTP Referrer in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258217/getting-the-http-referrer-in-asp-net)

But be aware that there won't always be a referrer. Some people consider this to be a privacy issue, and will set their browsers not to send a referrer header. The only way to know what URL the user came from "no matter what" is to have control over the generation of the URL in the first place and place a unique token on the URL so you can recognize which page the URL was generated for.

Comment: Note that Request.UrlReferrer is checking ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]

Answer (score 2):

and with javascript / Jquery perhaps document.referrer as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148177/the-right-way-to-get-http-referrer-from-jquery)